# How to show every UTXOs of each address in bitcoin core?

Tags: bitcoin-core

We only get balance of all addresses in bitcoin core, but how to show every UTXOs of each address in bitcoin core?

Comment: I think you will be able to do what you want using `listunspent`. [listunspent command](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/listunspent.html)

Comment: but listunspent only show the addresses whose UTXO is not zero. I want to list all addresses.

Comment: UTXO stands for unspent transaction output. So there is no zero UTXO. `listunpsent` will show you all UTXO from your wallet. The number of addresses is really large, you can consider it infinite in order to understand the magnitude. If you only want to see a list of addresses with 0 balance, you can just generate new addresses with [getnewaddress](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/getnewaddress.html). You can also use [listtransactions](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/listtransactions.html) to see all transactions that are already spent and get addresses from there.